# Android onConfigurationChanged() only in certain cases

Tags: android, configuration, orientation

I have stumbled on a problem, that, when the screen turns off while being in LANDSCAPE orientation, certain devices "rotate" the app back to PORTRAIT position (because the lockscreen is PORTRAIT only or something like that). I did a little research before posting this, and most popular work-around is to modify app's configuration change process to prevent activity being recreated after the configuration has changed.

But disabling activity recreation is not a solution for me, because my app supports both orientations with sepparate layout's etc.

So i would like to find out, is it possible to disable the configuration change only in special cases (Screen turned off and orientation is landscape)? Or is the right way to override onConfigurationChanged() then manually manage activity recreation inside that function (i guess simply setting different layout resources when orientation is changed simply wont cut it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is the right way to override onConfigurationChanged() then manually manage activity recreation inside that function?

Yes to an extent.

You cannot set the configChanges attribute programmatically. I guess it's to do with the way an Activity is created. They're created from the XML first and then the overridden methods in your activity implementation are invoked. There's nothing in the API that lets you change the configChanges attribute.

Now in your case it doesn't sound like you need to. If you support both orientations, then if the user locks the device and it rotates back why does it matter? From a UX perspective we know it's in portrait mode again. So should your app when it opens back up.

Comment: It is more of an optimization issue. Usually when this activity recreation happens, the debugger detects some sort of overload (Skipped .... frames messages). Another problem is that after the activity is recreated it is forced to background state (because the screen is off and activity is not visible), but not the onStop(). And this causes some other glitches, mostly because i have additional work inside onStop().

Comment: @aphelion I would need to see some code. But your problem is with your code and too much being done on the main thread it sounds.

Comment: my activity is 1,8K code lines long and it is way over max char limit in stackOverflow :D Regarding those messages, i dont get those messages on nromal cases (when rotating device etc). I only get this message when the bug in question appears.